# Setting User Agent for AVPlayer in DELPHI

Tags: delphi, avplayer, firemonkey

I am trying to set a `User Agent` for `AvPlayer` in Delphi based on the short code below:

```
NSMutableDictionary* * *headers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[headers setObject:@"YourHeader"forKey:@"User-Agent"];
self.urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:self.videoURL options:@{@"AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey" : headers}];
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.urlAsset];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
```

I am having trouble with this part:

```
options:@{@"AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey" : headers}
```

I have declared headers as `NSMutableDictionary` and `setobject` with the necessary fields, but how should I assign that to the key `AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey`?

I am using `ALVideoPlayer` from `Alcinoe` library and I need to set user agent there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *appears* to be doing the equivalent of this:

```
uses
  Macapi.Foundation, Macapi.Helpers, Macapi.AVFoundation;

var
  LDictionary: Pointer;
  LOptions: NSDictionary;
  LURLAsset: AVURLAsset;
  LVideoURL: NSURL;
begin
  // Make sure you initialize LVideoURL with whatever value it is expecting
  LDictionary := TNSDictionary.OCClass.dictionaryWithObject(StringToID('YourHeader'), StringToID('User-Agent'));
  LOptions := TNSDictionary.Wrap(TNSDictionary.OCClass.dictionaryWithObject(LDictionary, StringToID('AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey')));
  LURLAsset := TAVURLAsset.OCClass.URLAssetWithURL(LVideoURL, LOptions);
  // etc
end;
```